# How to Cut a video file and simultaneously convert it in to .mp4 format output using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, c#

**Here is the command to cut video file**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i inputvideo.avi -ss 0 -t 10 outputvideo.avi
```

**but i want to convert it from inputvideo.avi to outputvideo.mp4 format simultaneously**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, is there a question here?

Comment: yes, i want to cut a video from a video.avi file at the same time output will be a convert in to .mp4 format ..... how to do this

Comment: You should edit you question and clarify what you need.  In general more information is better.

Answer (score 0):

It's just

```
ffmpeg.exe -i inputvideo.avi -ss 0 -t 10 outputvideo.mp4
```

Depending on output requirements, you may need to add output options, like

```
ffmpeg.exe -i inputvideo.avi -ss 0 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p outputvideo.mp4
```

Comment: my output format will always .mp4 but input format will change in some times like ".3gp", ".m4v", "mp2", ".mpg", ".m4v" .. so in this scenario i should change the options

Comment: **Mulvya** I tried with your command 'ffmpeg.exe -i inputvideo.avi -ss 0 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p outputvideo.mp4' but it taking too long time after the starting duration is 40 to 60 min then rest of the conversion will take long time, example : 'ffmpeg.exe -i inputvideo.avi -ss 3000 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p outputvideo.mp4'   please give me any other best approach..... thanks in advance